# Create matrix all possible combinations for n numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix

So this is the first question that i post.
I'm having some problems with the creation of a matrix in Matlab.
I would like to create a matrix that containts *all* possible unique combinations for the numbers [1,2,3] (thus without any duplicate combinations).

Meaning that it will create a matrix that looks like the following:

1 2

1 3

1 2 3

2 3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can not create a matrix that is not rectangular.  Maybe you want a cell?

Comment: So combinations of 1 element should be excluded?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, not enough reputation...
As already said before, you can't have a non-rectangular matrix.

You can have the solution in cell-array form for instance, this code would do it (probably not the most efficient though):

```
function [ all_subsets ] = find_subsets( tab )
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    if (isempty(tab))
        all_subsets = {[]};
    else
        subsets_1 = find_subsets(tab(2:end));

        Y = num2cell(ones(1, length(subsets_1)) * tab(1));
        subsets_2 = arrayfun(@(L, X) add_elem(L, X), subsets_1, Y, 'UniformOutput', false);
        all_subsets = [subsets_1 subsets_2];
    end

end

function [L2] = add_elem(L, X)
    L2 = L{1};
    L2(end+1)=X{1};
end
```

And then you call:

```
find_subsets(1:3)
```

**EDIT**:

This is actually reversing the elements, you can correct that with a post processing, or with :

```
        subsets_1 = find_subsets(tab(1:end-1));

        Y = num2cell(ones(1, length(subsets_1)) * tab(end));
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have a matrix like that. You can only have:

```
1 2 NaN
1 3 NaN
1 2 3
2 3 NaN
```

You can have cell array like `A = cell(4,1); A{1} = [1, 2]; A{2} = ...`

And if you wish to get the code that would generate all those possibilities (what I believe you actually want), then change your question and show what you have attempted already.

Now lets assume this is what you really want. You should do recursion. Pseudocode solution would be like:

```
generatelist(numbers)
if numbers is empty, return [];
else return cell array length numbers+1, where first element is empty and the remaining ones have that numberX + output of generatelist(numbers > numberX).
```

To get rid of single element answers, parse them out at the end, it will simplify recursion part slightly. 
To get the matrix, find the longest cell and number of the combination, create matrix with nans and fill the values.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it only answers my comment. Either answer the question or put it as a comment.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I saw your comment after I submitted my solution, and in fact the matrix with NaN does answer the "create matrix" part. Except if what was really desired was to get the code to create all the combinations, not putting them in a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for agreeing with me in that you have not answered what OP desires. Then this answer is bad.

Comment: @AnderBiguri So for question that wants to create a matrix of combinations, answer should be the code to generate combinations? These are fundamentally different questions. One is answered like: create cell array or append nans to data. The other is answered by code that does recursion. Or, in this simple enough case, even a code that would create 8x3 array with nan, nan, nan -> 1, 2, 3 = all binary numbers from 0 to 7, sequence defined by binary value. Then parsed out cases that have <2 not-nans.